# what is the right way to save an entity using doctrine 2 and code igniter 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

Do I create a new entity in the controller and set all the fields with what I receive on $POST or there is an automatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a bit scarce in information but ordinarily, yes you have to create a new entity implicitly

```
$entity = new Entity;
$entity->setFoo($bar);
$this->entityManager->persist($entity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: You can find one here: http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/  Otherwise google is your friend ;)